# why is appendChild not working on <li> template tag

Tags: javascript, html, dom, browser

I have this JS and HTML content:

```js
const parent = document.querySelector('#parent');
const choices = parent.dataset.choices.split(",")

const childTplt = document.querySelector('#children');
for (c of choices) {
  let child = childTplt.content.cloneNode(true);

  child.appendChild(document.createTextNode(c));
  parent.appendChild(child);
}
```

```html
<ul id="parent" data-choices="one,two,three">
</ul>
<template id="children">
   <li> </li> 
</template>
```

and end up with this on my page:

```
<ul id="parent" data-choices="one,two,three"> 
  <li> </li> 
one
  <li> </li> 
two
  <li> </li> 
three</ul>
```

Why is that text content ends up as sibling of `<li>` and not as an actual children (inside of `<li></li>` ?

thanks for your input!

Comment: I'm not sure about this, but you may need to extract `.firstElementChild` from the content fragment you get from the template. That'll give you the `<li>` node, I think. *edit* yes, that works.

Answer (score 2):

The `.content` property of a template element is a document fragment; it is *not* the `<li>` element. In your case, the template is simple, so you can just reference the first child of the fragment:

```
  let child = childTplt.content.firstElementChild.cloneNode(true);
```

Comment: This worked!. I wanted to stay away from createElement (that's the point, I think, behind using template elements). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
function function1() {
  var ul = document.getElementById("list");
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  li.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Four"));
  li.setAttribute("id", "element4"); 
  ul.appendChild(li);
  alert(li.id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the loop above, you are appending `c` (one, two, three), then appending a cloned version of what is inside `#children`.

```
for (c of choices) {
  let child = childTplt.content.cloneNode(true);

  child.appendChild(document.createTextNode(c)); //will append 'one'
  parent.appendChild(child); //will append <li></li>
}
```

You can replace it with this loop and it will do what you are aiming for:

```
for (c of choices) {
    let li = document.createElement('li');
    li.append(c);
    parent.append(li);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The **template** tag has no immediate children. If you look at the properties of the **template** tag via console.log , you will see the *property children*: show HTMLCollection. The tags that are inside the  tag are stored inside the "content" property and there it shows that HMTLCollection[1] (in your case). In this collection, the `<li>` tag has an index of 0. I hope you understand everything else. That's all.

```
    const parent = document.querySelector('#parent');
    const choices = parent.dataset.choices.split(",");

    const [childTplt] = document.getElementsByTagName("template");

    for (c of choices) {
       let child = childTplt.content.children[0].cloneNode(true);  
       child.appendChild(document.createTextNode(c));
       parent.appendChild(child);
    }
```